# Powershell: Find installed Antivirus, filtering out Windows Defender

Tags: windows, powershell, antivirus

all.

I have a PowerShell script which will detect antivirus software installed in Windows (it's actually fairly common).  The problem is, I want it to filter Windows Defender, especially since Windows 8, 8.1, and 10 come with it installed.  I want my script to indicate whether or not Windows Defender if the ONLY antivirus software present and give a different output if it is.

Here's what I have so far...

```
function Get-AntivirusName { 
[cmdletBinding()]     
param ( 
[string]$ComputerName = "$env:computername" , 
$Credential 
) 
    BEGIN  
        { 
            $wmiQuery = "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct" 
        } 
    PROCESS  
        {    
            $AntivirusProduct = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Query $wmiQuery  @psboundparameters         
            $AntivirusNames = $AntivirusProduct.displayName       
            if ($AntivirusNames -eq "") {
                Write-host "Anti-Virus is NOT installed!"
            } 
            elseif ($AntivirusNames -eq "Windows Defender") {
                Write-host "ONLY Windows Defender is installed!"
            }
            else {
                Write-host "Anti-Virus is installed (" + $AntivirusNames + ")."
            }

        } 
     END { 
         } 
}

Get-AntivirusName
```

The result is, no matter which other antivirus software apps are installed, it keeps telling me only Windows Defender is installed.  Can someone point out what I'm missing?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it's checking each element of the array in the elseif statement so is true even if there are multiple results. You could add a condition that there is just one result as follows:

```
elseif ($AntivirusNames -eq "Windows Defender" -and $AntivirusNames.count -eq 1) {
                Write-host "ONLY Windows Defender is installed!"
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would declare that `$AntivirusNames` is an array when you assign it, and then use a switch to loop through the results.

```
function Get-AntivirusName { 
[cmdletBinding()]     
param ( 
[string]$ComputerName = "$env:computername" , 
$Credential 
) 
    BEGIN  
        { 
            $wmiQuery = "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct" 
        } 
    PROCESS  
        {    
            $AntivirusProduct = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Query $wmiQuery  @psboundparameters         
            [array]$AntivirusNames = $AntivirusProduct.displayName       
            Switch($AntivirusNames) {
                {$AntivirusNames.Count -eq 0}{"Anti-Virus is NOT installed!";Continue}
                {$AntivirusNames.Count -eq 1 -and $_ -eq "Windows Defender"} {"ONLY Windows Defender is installed!";Continue}
                {$_ -ne "Windows Defender"} {"Anti-Virus is installed ($_)."}
           }
} 
     END { 
         } 
}
Get-AntivirusName
```

So that switch... If there are zero results, declare that there is no AV installed. If there is 1 result, and it is Windows Defender, declare that. Otherwise if the current result is not Windows Defender output what the actual AV is.

On a side note, since you are not allowing an array of anything in your parameters you could just skip the `BEGINING` and `PROCESS` and stuff all of your code into the `END`, at which point you can skip declaring all of those blocks.

```
function Get-AntivirusName { 
[cmdletBinding()]     
param ( 
[string]$ComputerName = "$env:computername" , 
$Credential 
) 
    $wmiQuery = "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct" 
    $AntivirusProduct = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Query $wmiQuery  @psboundparameters         
    [array]$AntivirusNames = $AntivirusProduct.displayName       
    Switch($AntivirusNames) {
        {$AntivirusNames.Count -eq 0}{"Anti-Virus is NOT installed!";Continue}
        {$AntivirusNames.Count -eq 1 -and $_ -eq "Windows Defender"} {Write-host "ONLY Windows Defender is installed!";Continue}
        {$_ -ne "Windows Defender"} {"Anti-Virus is installed ($_)."}
   }
}
Get-AntivirusName
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is:

```
$AntivirusProduct = Get-WmiObject ...
$AntivirusNames -eq "Windows Defender"
```

When `Get-WmiObject` returns a single item, `$AntivirusNames` becomes a string, and the `-eq` tests if it matches the literal string.

When `Get-WmiObject` returns multiple items, `$AntivirusNames` becomes an array, and the `-eq` starts being a filter, filtering out items which match the literal string. i.e. if the array contains "Windows Defender", which it does.