# Uninstall packages (3rd party anti virus) in windows 10 using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to uninstall packages using the PowerShell command and script. Every time I run the command it runs and does nothing moreover can't find any logs of it. I tried Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/uninstall-package?view=powershell-7.1 In stack overflow similar problem [Powershell: Find installed Antivirus, filtering out Windows Defender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403076/powershell-find-installed-antivirus-filtering-out-windows-defender?rq=1) to find the installed antivirus. But When I want to uninstall it simply does nothing.

```
# Get-Package -Provider Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller
$appToRemove = Get-Package -IncludeWindowsInstaller -Name Avast
Write-Output $appToRemove
Uninstall-Package $appToRemove -Force -AllVersions -Confirm
```

I have tried several solutions and stuck for 1 week. Can anyone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Removing anti virus software can be really hard to do.. Perhaps in this case you need to use the uninstall application [avastclear](https://www.avast.com/uninstall-utility) to get rid of it?

Comment: The Avast vendor uninstaller kills a couple of processes before running the uninstall action. So I don't think it will be as simple as just attempting to remove the package. Are you specifically looking just to remove Avast? Or is it everything other than MS Defender?

Comment: I am trying to remove all general anti-virus except MS defender. Not particularly avast. @SolidSid

Comment: Is there any script to uninstall all antivirus products? @Theo

Comment: I'm not sure how that's going to be possible without knowing which AV products will be on the system. Each product may have different uninstall procedures that you would have to account for. I think your objective should be split into 2 tasks - 1. Find AV products and confirm the uninstall procedure 2. Run the uninstall procedure

Comment: I can find the AV products but really don't know how to run the uninstall procedure. I mean I tried a lots of scripts but no good luck

Comment: _Is there any script to uninstall all antivirus products?_ short answer: **no**. As @SolidSid also commented, each AV product can have its own uninstaller and usually it can only be done if processes are stopped first. Normally, you would not have permissions to do so..